# Power Query: Replace values without converting integers / whole numbers to floating point / decimal numbers?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

### Minimum Working Example

Power Query M

```
let
    Source = #table({"col"},{{1},{null}}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"col", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type",null,Int64.From(0),Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"col"})
in
    #"Replaced Value"
```

In `#"Changed Type"`, the column is of type "Whole Number". In `#"Replaced Value"`, the column is of type "Decimal Number", even when using a `newValue` of `Int64.From(0)` instead of just `0`.

**Why is the data type of the column changing and how can I prevent it?**

Comment: Interesting. Table.ReplaceValue gets you Decimal and Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {"col", each  _?? 0  }) gets you Any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old bug documented [here](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Issues/Bug-Table-ReplaceValue-kills-all-column-types/idi-p/225088/page/2#comments). Even with a custom replace function, you still can't fix it and can only convert to a primitive like *number*.

```
let
    Source = #table({"col"},{{1},{null}}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"col", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type",each [col],0,(x,y,z) as number => if y = null then z else x, {"col"})
in
    #"Replaced Value"
```